# Add rows to a PySpark df based on a condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to "duplicate" the rows the same number of times that the difference between two dates in the df. I have this dataframe:

[image]

So I need to explode the number of rows of the df to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all dates between `D1` and `D2` using [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#sequence) and then [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#explode) the dates:

```python
df = ...
df.withColumn("D1", F.explode(F.expr("sequence(D1,D2)"))) \
    .drop("D2").show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+----------+
|A  |B  |C  |D1        |
+---+---+---+----------+
|1  |2  |3  |2019-01-01|
|1  |2  |3  |2019-01-02|
|1  |2  |3  |2019-01-03|
+---+---+---+----------+
```